# Vw caddy bakkie with a 1.8 mp9 conversion

Tags: overheating

I have had the van for over a year an only a week ago has it now started overheating.
I have done the radiator switch,just done the water pump and today the head gasket witch to me looked to start with.....I done it anyway an the van is still over heating. The thermostat was never there so I left it out but cannot understand why it overheats. The thin pipe leading from the radiator to the water bottle is really swealing when it's hot also the fan kicks in once but as heat rises on the guage the fan will no longer kick in.

Can anyone help me plsss??

Comment: Did the new radiator come from a salvage yard or was it brand new?  Sounds like there is a blockage

Comment: It's the sAme radiator the car came with I only changed the fan switch.

Comment: what year is it?  Is the "water bottle" the overflow tank, or is it one of those designs where the coolant is stored outside of the radiator?